# Server-Sent Event is not working- Browsers can not listen any events of Server-Sent Event

Tags: html, jsp, server-sent-events

I am implementing of server-sent event(HTML5) in my project without using node.js, It is just simple webpage(another JSP page) call and i get response from it. But when i get response from it but none of method/function(onopen,onmessage or onerror) is execute...

Client Code:

```
if (!!window.EventSource) {
            var source=new EventSource("kitAvailCall.jsp");
            source.onopen = function(){
                alert("Kit is not available");
                source.close();
            };
            source.onmessage=function(event){
                console.log(event.data);
                alert("Kit is not available");
            }
            source.onerror =function(){
                console.log("EventSOurce: Getting error call");
                alert("Kit is not available");
            }
        }
```

Server-side code:

```
try{
    while(true) {
        Thread.sleep(15000);
        String IpAddress = (String) session.getAttribute("IPName");
        boolean bool;
        if(IpAddress != null && ((new Date()).getTime() - session.getLastAccessedTime())/1000 > 28){
            bool = sample.pingToKit((String) session.getAttribute("IPName"));
            System.out.println("Long polling request: "+bool);
            //if bool is false then i want to quit loop and back to browser
            if(bool == false){
                response.setHeader("Content-Type","text/event-stream");
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                out.print("data: " + bool);
                out.flush();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Going bad CONN:"+ e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much of java, but i could conjecture that you might be listening to the same controller/jsp servlet(whatever routes data in java) which you made to send as streaming.
Listen on a page other than kitavailcall.jsp. This script is meant only for streaming, use another view/html page other than kitavailcall.jsp
 The thing you have to understand is, SSE is a concurrent process, you create another page and run on that page with the javascript(client code) included in that page. And your server should support multi-threading as well.

Comment: my Client code is on index.jsp. and i am listening kitavailcall.jsp.